# Core spotlight description get truncated

Tags: objective-c, ios9, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I have noticed that core spotlight description get truncated even if description character length is under 150.

> Apple says : As with titles, long descriptions can also get truncated, so it’s best to limit your description to 300 characters.

I was wondering Why the core spotlight description get truncated even though the character length is less than 150 as Apple recommended to have limit 300.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Wild guess (haven't played with CoreSpotlight yet), could it be related to the device and the space it provides (screen size, zoom is on/off)?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can manually insert a newline in the title string, and it will use 2 lines, but will not autowrap to the next line without it.

Answer (score 0):

How much truncation will happen depends on various factors, including but not limited to:

- the avatar size
- the title length
- whether its a top hit result or a normal suggestion

Also new line `\n` doesn't work in Content description. I suggest you can separate different values using `|` sign. Core light Search result UI is very limited in terms of how much you can customise.